# how to read only one packet data in async boost?

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I have one tcp client that need read data via tcp
but i need read one tcp packet data at each time.

I usethis code:

```
        socket_[socket_index]->async_receive(
            boost::asio::buffer(buf, max_size),
            boost::bind(
              &pipe::handle_read, shared_from_this(),
              boost::asio::placeholders::error,
              socket_index,
              boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

but sometime I read more than one packet.how I need change it to read only one packet data?

Comment: TCP is a stream protocol on top of IP and therefore not packed based, unlike IP itself.

Comment: If you are using TCP and considering "packets", you are doing it wrong. Perhaps you could tell us your final goal and we might help with that ?

Comment: @MSalters yes I know. But in sending data is flag nodelay is any way  for reading data?

Comment: @ereOn my goal is port packet between to tcp object via my destop machine for sniffig and debuging.

Comment: As MSalters said, TCP is stream based and therefore, you **cannot** except data to be received the same way you sent it. Even with the  `nodelay` flag, the receiving host could decide to present half a packet or two packets at once while transferring information to the upper layer. The only reliable way, if you want to use TCP, is to encode your "packets" in some custom format so that you can "extract" one or several of them unambiguously from the stream upon reception.

Comment: To follow up on what @ereOn suggested, typically data sent over TCP is self-defining in that you first encode/extract a length (such that the value is endianness-independent), and then read `length` bytes, and that data is your protocol's 'packet', or (clearer) message.  You can never guarantee that a given socket read will return the same data that was sent on a single socket call on the sending side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just can't. You have your networking concepts confused, TCP is higher-level than that.

Use UDP if you really need to manipulate individual packets. For your minimal case, it's easy to switch.

Answer (score 1):

TCP is not packet-oriented - its stream of data. Packets can be merged together on any side and so on. I use following technique to read packet:

```
async_read(sock, asio::buffer(buf, sizeof(packet_header)), ...
```

E.g. reading only reader of packet. Now, i have full logical packet length in async read handler, so i do `asio::read` exactly number of bytes to read rest of logical packet; then setup `async_read` again to wait next packet header.

If you dont have logical packet length in your header, there is no way to detect where logical packet ends (in TCP case).

Answer (score 0):

The way this is controlled in practice is by passing the number of bytes you want to read instead of the size of your buffer.

You can put the number of bytes in your packet in a standard offset in a packet header.  First read the size of the packet header.  Then take the number of bytes in the packet (minus the size of the packet header) and read that many bytes.

Alternatively, go ahead and let it read more than one packet.  Process that packet.  After processing the first packet, determine if more than the packet was read, and if so, memcpy it to the beginning of the packet buffer.  If you have a whole packet in your buffer, process, if not, read more at the end of where your memcpy ended.